# NA values of raster have a fill when ploting in ggplot in combination with poligons of sf

Tags: ggplot2, r-raster, r-sf

I am trying to plot a raster and a simple feature in ggplot2, the graphs are just more beautiful to me than the base plots.

The problem I have is that the NA values of the raster have a grey fill, and I want them to be transparent to have a white background and the grid of ggplot2

Here is a reproducible example

#### Loading packages:

```
library(sf)
library(raster) 
library(tidyverse)
library(ggspatial)
library(rworldxtra)
```

#### Getting the data:

```
data("countriesHigh")
Peru <- countriesHigh %>% st_as_sf() %>% filter(ADMIN.1 == "Peru")
PeruRaster <- getData('alt', country='PER', mask=TRUE)
```

When I try to plot them together, my main problem is that the background (NA data) has a grey fill:

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = Peru) + theme_bw() + layer_spatial(PeruRaster)
```

[image]

Any idea on how to make the background fill transparent so that the grid of ggplot can be seen?

PS: I am also trying

```
ggplot() + layer_spatial(PeruRaster) + geom_sf(data = Peru, alpha = 0) + theme_bw()
```

now but the graph takes a while

Answer (score 9):

set this using the `na.value` argument within `scale_fill_continous`

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = Peru) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  layer_spatial(PeruRaster) +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "transparent")
```

Comment: Hello @sebdalgamo, it kind of works, but I needed transparent color, I tried with  na.value = "#00FFFFFF", but I didnt work

Comment: `scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "transparent")` should work.